# Skype not showing images recieved

Tags: image, skype, chatbot, gupshup

I am trying to create a bot and deploy it onto different platforms, but when I return images in the carousel for the chatbot, Skype doesn't render them, while the same works for Facebook and even on the web widget provided by Gupshup.

If you want to know the chatbot platform i'm using it would be [Gupshup](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/home) with api.ai hooked for nlp , do you know the problem i am encountering?

I have tried different ways of getting the image. First I got it from the site I am making the chatbot for, then I tried shortening the url using google and finally I tried uploading the image on Google drive.The image format is jpg could that be the issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeAQN.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update:7/5/2017] - Skype issue is now resolved. The carousel code that is working for Facebook Messenger will also work for Skype.

**Sample JSON for Carousel on Skype:**

```
{
"type": "catalogue",
"msgid": "cat_212",
"items": [{
        "title": "White T Shirt",
        "subtitle": "Soft cotton t-shirt \nXs, S, M, L \n$10",
        "imgurl": "https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/fashion/daily/2016/06/02/t-shirt/everlane.w710.h473.2x.jpg",
        "options": [{
                "type": "url",
                "title": "View Details",
                "url": "https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/fashion/daily/2016/06/02/t-shirt/everlane.w710.h473.2x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "title": "Buy"
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Grey T Shirt",
        "subtitle": "Soft cotton t-shirt \nXs, S, M, L \n$12",
        "imgurl": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0407/0829/products/Grey_t-shirt_front_1024x1024.jpg?v=1466588290",
        "options": [{
                "type": "url",
                "title": "View Details",
                "url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0407/0829/products/Grey_t-shirt_front_1024x1024.jpg?v=1466588290"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "title": "Buy"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

**Result:**
[image]

> Images are not loading for the carousel on Skype because there have
>   been recent changes in Microsoft framework which are not yet
>   incorporated in Gupshup's bot platform. Although next week you should
>   be able to see those images load once we at Gupshup pushes the fix
>   into production. There will be no need of changing the code from your
>   end as the same code for carousel works across the supported
>   platforms.
>
> I will update this answer once the fix is live into production.

PS: I work for Gupshup.

Comment: so it wasn't a skype issue after all? because the images did not render even after we had tried with luis and the microsoft bot framework itself . Thanks a lot for clearing it up

Comment: Also can you explain how the json object from api.ai is parsed by gupshup?

Comment: Can you please create another question on SO with specifics, so that I can answer it. It would be helpful for others too.